# Show that is $A$ is normal then $A$ commutes with some normal matrix with distinct eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

Let's $A$ be square matrix, i need a help to show that

if $A$ is normal then there existe $X$ a normal matrix with distinct eigenvalues such that $AX=XA$

if $A$ is normal then there existe $B$ a self-adjoint matrix with distinct eigenvalues such that $AB=BA$

I think about that, if $A$ is normale then $A^{*}=P(A)$ for some polynomial $P$, then $A$ commute with $P(A)$, so i took $X=P(A)$ but the problem is in eigenvalues, and i took $B=A^{*}A$

Thank you !

Comment: Do you know that normal implies diagonalizable?

Comment: Yes ! If $A$ is normal then it is diagonalizable  @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: Then can you find suitable $X$ in the special case that $A$ is in fact already diagonal?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen if $A$ is normal, then $A=UDU^{*}$ such that $D$ is diagonal, we took $X=UTU^{*}$ with $T$ diagonal and the diagonal elements are distinct .....is that right ?!